# Python + Selenium: How to switch to overlay

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, overlay

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("lnkClassInfo").click()
time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#popup input[value='BOOK THIS CLASS NOW']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

ERROR: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#popup input[value='BOOK THIS CLASS NOW']"}

[image: Main Page]

[image: Overlay]

Line 1 of my code allows me to click into the above time-slot on the Main Page, which triggers an Overlay to pop up. My goal is to click the class-booking button on the overlay. Based on my understanding, Python needs to switch to the overlay/iframe. Please advise on how to code this for my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

Relevant Main Page HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        setPageScroll('dashboard');

        $(".club-selections a").click(function () {
            $("#ctl00_cphContents_ddlClub").val($(this).attr('rel'));
            $("form:first").submit();
        });

        $(".schedule-selection a").click(function () {
            $("#ctl00_cphContents_ddlSchedule").val($(this).attr('rel'));
            $("form:first").submit();
        });

        $(".club-selections a[rel=" + $("#ctl00_cphContents_ddlClub").val() + "]").addClass('selected');
        $(".schedule-selection a[rel=" + $("#ctl00_cphContents_ddlSchedule").val() + "]").addClass('selected');

        $(".lnkClassInfo").click(function () {
            $.colorbox({
                href: $(this).attr("href"),
                title: $(this).attr("title"),
                transition: 'fade', iframe: true,
                width: 566, height: 600,
                fixed: true
            });
            return false;
        });

        var FIREFOX = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

        if (FIREFOX) {
            $('.tbl-wrapper .tbl-container').scroll(function () {
                $('title').html($(this).scrollLeft());
                $(this).find('a.lnkClassInfo').css('margin-right', $(this).scrollLeft() + "px");
            });
        }

    });
</script>


<a href='popup/class-info.aspx?tcl_id=307632'     title='Class Info.'     style='line-height:74px; height:74px; top:413px;'     class='lnkClassInfo'><span class='class-name'>ICE II</span><span>- Zaf -<br />11:30 - 12:30 PM<br /><img src='https://trueclassbooking.com.sg/userfiles/class-tags/cover.jpg' alt='Cover' title='Cover' style='height:16px;' /></span></a>
```

Overlay HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#592954" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, user-scalable=yes" /><title>
CBSS System - Class Info.
</title>
<link href="https://trueclassbooking.com.sg/member/css/style.all.css?v=2.22.03" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="https://trueclassbooking.com.sg/member/css/ie.css?v=2.22.03" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="https://trueclassbooking.com.sg/member/css/ie8.css?v=2.22.03" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="class-info.aspx?tcl_id=307632" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>


<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="4B353318" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKm0IbODAKt8aSHB8YJdcVegLzMqZZLYYPUOKYp+jf1" />
</div>

    <!-- MESSENGER -->
    <div id="message-wrapper" class="popup-message-wrapper" title="Click to hide."></div>

    <!-- CONTENTS -->
    <div id="popup">


<div class="class-info">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="left al">
            <div class="time">11:30 - 12:30 PM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right ar" style='display:none;'>
            <span style="color:#b91be0"></span> SLOTS
            &nbsp; <span style="color:#999999;">|</span> &nbsp;
            <span style="color:#cc0066"></span> SLOTS AVAILABLE
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="left al">
            <div class="class-name">ICE II - Zaf</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right ar">
            <a id="ctl00_cphContents_btnBook" class="btn-gradient" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContents$btnBook','')">BOOK THIS CLASS NOW</a>


        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div class="description">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="left">
                ICE II
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <img src='https://trueclassbooking.com.sg/userfiles/class-tags/cover.jpg' alt='Cover' title='Cover' style='height:16px;' />
            </div>
        </div>
        <p><span style="font-size:24px"><strong>Indoor Cycling Experience (I.C.E.) I</strong></span><br />
Highly recommended for those who want a solid foundation in bike set-up &amp; cycling technique. A high energy workout, this indoor cycling workout is paced with light and music settings to create a vibrant atmosphere.<br />
&nbsp;<br />
Push your limits and get intense through warm-up, sprints, climbs and cool-down segments , with changing body positions, pedal speed and resistance.<br />
&nbsp;<br />
<span style="font-size:24px"><strong>Indoor Cycling Experience (I.C.E.) II</strong></span><br />
This programme has proven to be one of the most well-received fat-loss programmes thus far! Simple yet hyper-challenging!<br />
&nbsp;<br />
<span style="font-size:24px"><strong>Indoor Cycling Experience (I.C.E.) III</strong></span><br />
Expectations from participants as well as instructors alike are astronomical! Must have had regular training with Spin II to attempt this class.        
</p>
    </div>
</div>


    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://trueclassbooking.com.sg/member/js/script.all.js?v=2.22.03"></script>
<!-- JAVSCRIPTS -->


<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g;         
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-45242383-1', 'trueclassbooking.com.sg');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<!-- EXCEPTIONS -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not switch to overlay as it's just a simple modal window (`div` node). And also target element doesn't looks like an `input`, but a link

```
<a id="ctl00_cphContents_btnBook" class="btn-gradient" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContents$btnBook','')">BOOK THIS CLASS NOW</a>
```

Try below to wait for link to appear and click it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_class_name("lnkClassInfo").click()
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "BOOK THIS CLASS NOW"))).click()
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) you can find more info about what is `iframe` and how it might looks like...

Comment: Hi @Andersson, thank you for the advice but I got a TimeoutException error after running the code. For some reason, the webdriver seems unable to detect the modal window. I tried getting it to click the text link using by_class_name (i.e. btn-gradient) and it went on to click on a similarly named link on the main page instead.

Comment: Hm... Maybe you're right and it is an `iframe` :))) Can you check an ancestors?

Comment: So I developed a work-around:  `elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("lnkClassInfo")  print (elem.get_attribute("href"))  elem_url = elem.get_attribute("href") 
 driver.get(elem_url)  driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-gradient").click()`
Doing so leads the driver to fully open the overlay in the same tab, thus allowing me to interact with it.
Still curious about how to interact with the overlay though.

Comment: You can simply try F12 -> switch to HTML inspector -> CTRL + F -> enter "iframe". Found something?

Comment: `$(".lnkClassInfo").click(function () {
                $.colorbox({
                    href: $(this).attr("href"),
                    title: $(this).attr("title"),
                    transition: 'fade', iframe: true,
                    width: 566, height: 600,
                    fixed: true
                });
                return false;
            });`
This is the only thing to show up. Odd huh..

Comment: Then it's not an `iframe` :) Try couple more selectors: `(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "BOOK THIS CLASS NOW")`, `(By.XPATH, "//div[.='ICE II - Zaf']/following::a")`, `(By.ID, "ctl00_cphContents_btnBook")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but still can't get webdriver to click on them i.e. signup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphContents_btnBook']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", signup)
Can you help me peer into the HTML on what I'm missing? 
Main page (https://pastebin.com/jTs5iVAr) and the overlay (https://pastebin.com/JnqxE5yY).

Comment: Note: I've to use another class as the previous ICE class has expired.